# What is the default keep-alive time out in Internet Explorer 11?

Tags: internet-explorer, http, internet-explorer-11

I know the default setting up to IE 7.0 is one minute. But what about IE 11?

Answer (score 3):

I've just experimentally verified the timeout is still one minute in IE 11.
(checked on a quite new machine with Windows 8.1, where the IE 7.0 never was installed)

The [registry settings for changing the timeout](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/813827) work in IE 11 as well.

Comment: link's dead. regedit HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\InternetSettings new DWORD KeepAliveTimeout which is in milliseconds.